# HTML & CSS: Vertical Flow Layout (columnar style), how to implement?

Tags: html, css

The standard CSS/html positioning of "flowing" Elements is horizontal (row based) => `float:left`;. What do I need to do, to position them like in the example below (columnar style). Are there any CSS tags to set this somewhere? (Ideally I do not want to setup a grid, this should happen the same way automatically lilke it does in the float:left style...)

```
+---------------------------+
|  DivBox1                  |
|  DivBox2                  |
|  DivBox3                  |
+---------------------------+
```

After adding: 2 more boxes:

```
+----------------------------+
|  DivBox1  DivBox4          |
|  DivBox2  DivBox5          |
|  DivBox3                   |
+----------------------------+
```

Finally, after adding 2 more boxes it would look like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
|  DivBox1  DivBox4  DivBox7  |
|  DivBox2  DivBox5           |
|  DivBox3  DivBox6           |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: Ideally it should be based on standards. Its OK if it is based only on newer standards likek css3 and html5 (and therefore all compliant browsers). but it would also be good if older browsers supported this, but this is no requirement)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is [CSS3 Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns) (for the effect you talk about, the [Height Balancing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns#Height_Balancing) section is a good thing to read) which is supported in newer browsers and would look something like

```
#box {
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
}
```

And would support [IE 10, FF, and Chrome](http://caniuse.com/#search=columns).

Or, you can use a tool like [Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to get column like effects on a page (though this requires JS to work) and support more browsers.

Comment: Is there some option for Masonry.js for this kind of effect? (With a brief search I couldn't find such)

Comment: @Touko No, Masonry doesn't have the option for the this type of layout in particular, it is just the most popular library for columns. There are, however, lots of other libraries made for this specific thing more particularly. I can't recommend one, as I've never used any, but a quick search for JS columns should yield lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to each of the divs and style it with something like:

```
.myDiv
{
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Now when I read a bit more correcly I see that I simplied it a bit. You need to do a bit more. You could try adding container divs with the style above and put three divs in each with float left but I don´t have a solution without adding markup.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the problem described can be solved in a more flexible manner using Flexbox layout. Requires the latest and greatest browser (IE 11+).

http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html#column

http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/