# How can I fill a 5 different columns inside an HTML table with 5 different result sets from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a table with the following structure, let's name the header with letters:

```
A | B | C | D | E
```

I would like to perform 5 different queries to my mysql server and I would like to fill the whole table with them in the following way:

The first result-set to complete the whole `A` column, then with the other result I would like to complete de column `B`, and then the 3 that left.

If I use a for statement, the for fills them in that way: After I echoed the table headers, it begins filling the SECOND cell of column `A`, then the SECOND cell for column `B`, then the SECOND cell of `C` until it completes the whole row.

And what I do want is to complete the first cell of column `A`, then the second cell of column `A`, then the 3 cell of column `A` and so on.

When I completed the whole column. I would like to complete the column `B`, then `C`, `D`, and `E`.

I hope I was clear enough.

I would like to implement this with PHP and using a for loop.

Comment: It's a little trickier than going from left to right, but it's definitely possible. What code have you written so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML & CSS: Vertical Flow Layout (columnar style), how to implement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119347/html-css-vertical-flow-layout-columnar-style-how-to-implement)

Comment: The task can be done, but you need to clarify your question, as in:

The table in the database has the same number of rows as the number of rows in the HTML table?

Comment: The HTML table has the same rows always. Because this is for an scheduler that starts at 8 am and ends 9 pm. Then is going to be populated with some information requested from the DB. That information is not stored ( all ) into the DB, but its created while querying the DB. But, as I told you, the HTML table has the same number of rows. Then, the rows are gonna be populated. I hope I was clear enough now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just posted an answer and example code to a very similar question. It assumes you have only 1 data set, but want to display it in columns. You can find that answer here:
[Is it possible to fill a table with values in column wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111815/is-it-possible-to-fill-a-table-with-values-in-column-wise/21036717#21036717)
If you like the answer, please vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this as a visual effect?  If that is the case you are better off loading all of the cells first, and put them into label with Visible="false" then use JQuery and come back through and orderly by column A and by cell then B and by cell etc set visible="true" to give that rolled out effect of filling column a then b.

Answer (score 0):

First idea off the top of my head is to layout the whole table when you loop through the first column values.  So when you dump the value also add the empty cells for that row.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Value 1</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

Then when you are looping through the subsequent column values place them in the right cell using jquery.

Comment: I would like to avoid the usage of jQuery. I just want to do this iterating with PHP alone.