# Is it possible to fill a table with values in column wise?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to fill table with values in column wise. For example

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
for ($j=0;$j<6;$j++)
{
echo "<tr>";
for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
{
echo "<td>".$j.$i."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

The output becomes

```
00  01  02  03  04  05
10  11  12  13  14  15
20  21  22  23  24  25
30  31  32  33  34  35
40  41  42  43  44  45
50  51  52  53  54  55
```

But i wanted the table to look like

```
00  10  20  30  40  50
01  11  21  31  41  51
02  12  22  32  42  52
03  13  23  33  43  53
04  14  24  34  44  54
05  15  25  35  45  55
```

I came with up with a condition by not changing values that fill in the table. (Altering echo from $j.$i to $i.$j brings that appearance but i wanted to fill data in column wise). How it become possible?

Answer (score 0):

Without even going into details of the JS issues, your PHP is completely wrong (which you should be able to see if you looked at the HTML that your php is generating):

```
echo '<li value"'.$i.'" id="'.$i.'" onclick=loadXmlDoc("'.$i,$variable.'")>'.$i.'</li>';<br>
```

should be something more like this:

```
echo '<li value="'.$i.'" id="'.$i.'" onclick="loadXmlDoc(\''.$i.'\',\''.$variable.\''")>'.$i.'</li><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this:

```
$variable1="xyz";
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{   
    echo '<li value"'.$i.'" id="'.$i.'" onclick=loadXmlDoc("'.$i,$variable.'")>'.$i.'</li>';<br>
}
```

needs to be:

```
$variable1="xyz";
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{   
    echo '<li value="'.$i.'" id="'.$i.'" onclick=loadXmlDoc(\''.$i.'\',\''.$variable.'\')>'.$i.'</li>';<br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you really do it, old-school style, fully commented for explanation.

```
 <?php
 //NOTE: This excercise would be slightly easier if you just used php's DomDocument class because you wouldn't 
 //need to waste some logic determining whether to open/close the table rows, but here it is just echoing
 //out some straight html 

//The example data
$data_set = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");
//at the very least, you'll need to know how many columns you want to format the data into...
$number_of_columns = 5; 
//count the data items
$number_of_data_items=count($data_set);
//determine how many rows you'll need to display the data in the given number of columns
$num_rows=ceil($number_of_data_items/$number_of_columns);
//determine exactly how many cells it will take to display the data
$num_cells=$num_rows*$number_of_columns;

//now that we have enough info to output the table...
//init some counters
$row_count=0;
$column_count=0;
//open the table element
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>";
for($i=0;$i<$num_cells;$i++){

    $column_count++; 
    $index = $row_count + ($num_rows * ($column_count-1) );
    if( $column_count==1 ){ 
        echo "<tr>";
    } 

    if(  $index < $number_of_data_items){ 
        echo  "<td>Item :".($index+1)."</td>"; //Display the number of the data item we are
        echo  "<td>".$data_set[$index]."</td>"; //Display the actual data item
        echo "<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>"; //Add some extra space between columns
    }else{ 
        //write empty cells if the data set doesn't completely fill the last column
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";    
        echo "<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";  
    } 
    if($number_of_columns == $column_count){ 
        echo "</tr>";
        $row_count++; 
        $column_count=0;
    } 
} 
//close the table element
echo "</table>";
?>
```