# CSS: how to make a list wrap vertically?

Tags: css

I have a somewhat long list and want it to "wrap" into vertical columns. Say I have a list of 10 items and I want it to be 5 items per column, the layout should be like this:

```
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5   10
```

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML & CSS: Vertical Flow Layout (columnar style), how to implement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119347/html-css-vertical-flow-layout-columnar-style-how-to-implement)

Answer (score 17):

Sorry, it's actually super simple:

```
ul {
-webkit-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
}
```

Check out this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fYmF/1/)

Comment: `width:50%;`? Does that mean 2 columns? Your example uses `760px;`, though.

Comment: So is this 2 columns? I don't know in advance how many columns the list should be. I know how many list items per column I want, though.

Comment: Ok, it's really easy. Go look now

Comment: So, again, this is 2 columns, right? What if my list is really long and it needs to be 3 columns? The point is that I do not know in advance how many items will be in my list. All I know is that I want up to a certain number of list items per column.

Comment: Does it matter how many I need in each column? Let's say 5 or 7 or 10. Does the solution change depending on the number of list items in each column?

Comment: Maybe you should use a table?

Comment: No. My content is a list. It's not tabular data.

Comment: Well sorry, I don't know. I'm sure you could do this in javascript though.

Answer (score 8):

Use [CSS3 columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/). In particular, if you set `column-width`, it should make as many columns as necessary. If you want it to prefer going down rather than giving each column an equal number amount of items, you can set `column-fill` to `auto`.

Comment: Can you please show me the CSS? My list items will not always be 10 items. But I can specify in advance how many list items I want in each column.

Comment: So the variable for me will be the `ul` height property, right?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Yes. The `ul`'s height should be enough to fit all of your list items in one column.

Comment: Looks like this was enough to make it work: `{ height: 120px; -webkit-column-width: 100px; }`. Any problems if I do just that?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Yes. It will only work in WebKit browsers. Make sure to use `column-width` and `-moz-column-width` as well so it will work in the other browsers.

Comment: OK, it's working in Chrome and FF. It's NOT working on IE8. Suggestions?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Internet Explorer 8 does not support this CSS3 feature. Your question was tagged with CSS3, so I assumed it was okay to use CSS3 features. There is no pure-CSS way to do it without CSS3 features that is immediately obvious to me.