# Align non-equal height divs to top

Tags: css

I'm creating a portfolio with different height items. Each item is an `inline-block` div with a fixed width. So, I got 4 items in each row. I've aligned them vertically to top and it's fine so far. The problem begins since the 2nd row. I need each item to be aligned regarding to its upper item, not the row. **I'd like to do it by pure CSS right in my styles codes. Hopefully, no using plugin, library or pre-maid code**. See the image to find out more about my meaning.

[image]

The code I got is as below.
HTML (by PHP):

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <?php foreach($portfolio as $work) : ?>
        <div class="work">
            <div class="work-image">
                <img src="images/<?php echo $work[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $work[1]; ?>">
                <h5 class="work-title"><?php echo $work[1]; ?></h5>
            </div>

            <div class="work-description">
                <?php echo $work[2]; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="work-tech">
                <h5><?php echo $lang['TECHNOLOGIES']; ?></h5>
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($work[4] as $tech) : ?>
                    <li class="tech-item"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> <?php echo $tech; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

CSS (by LESS):

```
#portfolio {
    background: url('../images/portfolio-bg.jpg') repeat-y center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    .portfolio {
        text-align: center;
        .work {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 280px;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 0;
            vertical-align: top;
            background: green;
            .work-image {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 186px;
                overflow: hidden;
                background: black;
                img {

                }
                .work-title {
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 10px;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    color: red;
                }
            }
            .work-description {
                padding: 15px;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: justify;
            }
            .work-tech {
                padding: 15px;
                text-align: left;
                h5 {
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119347/html-css-vertical-flow-layout-columnar-style-how-to-implement

Comment: Use columns instead of rows or use Masonry plugin.

Comment: Both answers refer me to use the float property. I wouldn't like to use it because I'd like the items to be aligned center as well. But if I got no choice, I'll use the code that I've written based on Mansory before. https://github.com/arashtad/Arashtad-Masonry-Flippers

Comment: Why don't you use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?